# SQL Compact database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-ce

I have been given 2 files .DB and .sdf to work with. I have googled it a little and found out that its SQL Compact database format. I really have no idea how to work with these database files.

I have found here on stackoverflow some 3rd party tools, bud they were all for windows (I am on Mac).

I have also tried to open it in SQLite but no success.

I need this data in my web app written in PHP. So conversion to MySQL or Postrge seems to be an ideal solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just ask the person that gave them to you to provide a SQL dump (table structure + data + indexes) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSSQL extension in PHP to work with these databases